# Одевать или надевать?

Tags: лексика

В каких случаях нужно говорить "надевать", а когда "одевать"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует очень распространенная ошибка, когда говорят, например, "я одела платье". Однако это в корне неверно. Одевать можно кого-то, а на себя - исключительно *надевать*.
Примеры: *"она **надела** пальто и пошла гулять", "она **одела** сына в пальто и пошла с ним гулять"*

Comment: Является ли неверным, с точки зрения нормативного русского, предложение «она одела сарафан (на себя)» ?

Answer (score 2):

Как проще запомнить: надеть одежду - одеть Надежду.

Comment: Надеть Надежду тоже можно, но это, простите, из другой оперы.

Answer (score 0):

Формально верно "одеть Надежду, надеть одежду", но в [этом видео](https://youtu.be/E0c9leDUFFU) приводится здравая мысль, что большинство носителей языка используют в большинстве случаев слово **одеть** вместо **надеть**.

Comment: Когда-то в русском языке существовал глагол "набуть", который отмер вследствие повсеместного использования "обуть". Мне бы не хотелось, чтобы то же произошло с "надеть".

Answer (score 0):

Если формально,и по отношении к  себе, то "надевать".Если кого-то то "одевать"
Интересно что в немецком (всежe индоевропейский!) отдельно выноситься ;) смысл если "надевать на голову".Вас поймут, если Вы "одеваете" или "надеваете" но принято,будучи Немцем грамотным, в таком случае напр. если фуражку, то "насаживать"= aufspitzen.